# what does it mean when you use "作“ as a measure word for people?

Tags: vocabulary

What does it mean when you use "作" as a measure word for people ? for example, in 沈从文‘s 《丈夫》 I read the line 都使这作丈夫的想起了村长同乡绅那些大人物的威风

Is 作 different from 位？

Comment: 作 is totally different from 位. In your case, 作 just happens to be replaceable by 位 ONLY after removing 的 in 丈夫的, making it: `都使这位丈夫想起了村长同乡绅那些大人物的威风`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not a measure word. It means `act as; be`.

`作丈夫的` could be translated literally as `The people who act as husband`, or just `The husband`.